# Invoke a function in context of a class instance or method for performance analysis

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, execution-time

Performance analysis question: Is there a way to execute a function in context of a class, or a method of a class?

I would like to analyze the performance of a specific segment of logic. What I envision is something like this

(Disclaimer: rough example just to illustrate a point. Will not compile).

```
const int DEBUG_LEVEL = 7;

class PerfWrapper {
public:
    PerfWrapper(int f) {} // Constructor: take function as argument
    void invoke() {} // Invoke the function passed as argument
    double execution_time() {
        begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        // etc..
    } 
    double memory_usage() {}
private:
}
int foo() {
    int sum{0}
    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j<MAX; ++j) 
            sum += i * j;
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    if (DEBUG_LEVEL = 7)
        PerfWrapper p(foo); // Create an instance, passing foo as an argument

        // below foo() is called in context of the performance wrapper
        int myTime = p.invoke().execution_time(); // Invokes foo in context of p and tracks execution time
        int myMemory = p.invoke().memory_usage(); // Same, except gathering memory usage info.
        // etc..
    }
}
```

Here we have class PerfWrapper. When instantiated, resulting methods on the object have the ability to accept a function as an argument, and execute a function in context of the class. It will take perf measurements, results of which are accessible through the interface.

Note the "DEBUG_LEVEL" setting. If performance profiling is needed then simply set the DEBUG_LEVEL to 7.

Have you seen anything like this? If not, how is the analysis best accomplished? I know that it seems a bit out there, but hopefully not so much. Thx, Keith :^)

Comment: You can compare to how benchmarking libraries such as [nonius](https://nonius.io/) do it. Generally you *can* implement this (minus the memory usage probably), but I don't see the advantage of making it a class instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for function pointers, which could be used as shown in the following simplified code:

```
typedef int(*aFooFunctionType)(void);

class PerformanceTest {
public:
    PerformanceTest(aFooFunctionType fooFuncPtr) { m_fooFuncPtr = fooFuncPtr; }
    void test() {
        int x = m_fooFuncPtr();
        // do something with x (or not...)
    };
private:
    aFooFunctionType m_fooFuncPtr;
};


int fooFunc(void) {
    return 100;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    PerformanceTest pTest(fooFunc);
    pTest.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function pointers and `std::function` and the template version that takes any callable together with a make function or C++17 deduction guides.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap almost anything in a `std::function`. I would suggest use of a `std::function` in `PerfWrapper` to get the execution time. I don't have anything for measuring memory usage, though.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

class PerfWrapper
{
   public:

      PerfWrapper(std::function<void()> f) : f_(f), execution_time_{} {}

      void invoke()
      {
         auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
         f_();
         auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
         execution_time_ = end-begin;
      }

      double execution_time()
      {
         return execution_time_.count();
      } 

      std::function<void()> f_;
      std::chrono::duration<double> execution_time_;
};

unsigned long foo()
{
   unsigned long sum{0};
   for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
      for (int j=0; j<2000; ++j) 
         sum += i * j;
   return sum;
}

int main()
{
   PerfWrapper pr([](){std::cout << foo() << std::endl;});
   pr.invoke();
   std::cout << "Execution time: " << pr.execution_time() << std::endl;
}
```

Output on my setup:

```
99940005000000
Execution time: 0.0454077
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a template free function, with a reference parameter to extract the performance data.  This example will:

- Accept function pointers and functors (including `std::function`, which means it can work with methods, too).
- Return the same value the proxied function call returns, so you can use both the measurement data *and* the call result.

---

```
struct measurement {
    double execution_time;
    double memory_usage;
};

template <typename FN, typename... T>
inline auto measure(FN fn, measurement& m, T&&... args) -> decltype(fn(std::forward<T>(args)...))
{
    auto&& result = fn(std::forward<T>(args)...);

    m.execution_time = 0; // example
    m.memory_usage = 0;

    return result;
}
```